# Clojure: adding to a map

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure

If I have a vector of maps

```
(def v [{:key1 "value 1" :key2 "value2"} {:key1 "value 3" :key2 "value4"}])
```

and a map

```
(def m {:key3 "value2" :key4 "value5"})
```

How to add map m to all the maps in vector v where the values of 2 given keys (in this case key2 and key3) are equal?

The expected result would be this:

```
[{:key1 "value 1" :key2 "value2" :key3 "value2" :key4 "value5"} {:key1 "value 3" :key2 "value4"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to merge each map with m3 if key2 and k3 are equal:

```
(map (fn [x] (if (= (:key2 x) (:key3 m)) (merge m x) x)) v)
```

=>

```
({:key3 "value2", :key2 "value2", :key4 "value5", :key1 "value 1"} {:key2 "value4", :key1 "value 3"})
```

Comment: Yeah, mapv if the result needs to be a vector.

Comment: I have one more question, I have a situation like this,vector is (defn v2 []( map #(zipmap (create-keys ["url" "title"]) %) (func-contents ["url" "title"] "//event" data-url))) data-url is in this question http://bit.ly/1x83gYH and map is (defn v1[] (map #(zipmap  (create-keys ["name" "url"]) %) (func-contents ["name" "url"] "//artist" "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=The+Sound+of+Music&api_key=00c6b7abec24599649bfcecf19c08cf1"))). In this case it doesn't work, it adds the map anyway.